# How to make a view's background color match parent?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I use two parent views to wrap an image view and view, both parent views having background color.But it cannot displays correct background color

Now it uses the background color of theme, how to make the background same with parent background?

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/_scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="140dp"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:background="#6D9AB8">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#6D9AB8"
        android:padding="30dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:src="@mipmap/icon" />
        <View
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Setting the background color to transparent may be what you're looking for.

Answer (score -1):

You can set the BG of ImageView and View.

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:background="#6D9AB8"
            android:src="@mipmap/icon" />
        <View
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:background="#6D9AB8"
            />
```

Comment: I don't want to do that, because this imageview is from other xml, I will add to different linearlayout programmatically,  And these linearlayout have different background color, if I set background color to imageview, I need to create many version for each linearlayout. And I also don't want to change background at run-time, because that make my code complex.